# Angular 2-way binding not working

Tags: html, angularjs

Below is my code.2 way binding is not working as expected. Can you please point-out the mistake

```
<div id="list" class="form-group">
            <label for="attach" class="col-xs-2 control-label">{{ resource["gve.common.attach"] }}</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <ol class="marTop10">
                    <li class="exactFit" ng-repeat="files in attachList">{{ files.fileName }}</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>



$scope.populateView = function() 
    {
        $rootScope.inputSpin        = false;
        $rootScope.modifiedCaseData = $scope.problem;
        $scope.showReviewBtn        = $rootScope.showReviewBtn; 
        $scope.attachList = [];

        $scope.attachList.push({fileId:"100",fileName:"Test.pdf"});
        for(i in $scope.attachList) {
            console.log (i, $scope.attachList[i]);
        }
    };
```

fileName is not getting displayed in HTML {{files.fileName}} even though {fileId:"100",fileName:"Test.pdf"} is added to $scope.attachList

EDIT 1: I am sorry for not mentioning those details. ng-controller is already defined and populateView() is called from a different function.

EDIT 2: From console.log .

```
09:56:17.486 problemCtrl.js?gccm=1.0:185 0 Object {fileId: 100, fileName: "untitled 8.txt"}fileId: 100fileName: "untitled 8.txt"
```

Comment: I dont see ng-controller or ng-app. I hope that part is covered. Beyond that, `$scope.attachList` is assigned value inside `$scope.populateView` function but I don't see it being called anywhere.

Comment: Do a `console.log` inside that function which calls `populateView` after it is called to verify the value is set.

Comment: Hi here it is from the console.log 
09:56:17.486 problemCtrl.js?gccm=1.0:185 0 Object {fileId: 100, fileName: "untitled 8.txt"}fileId: 100fileName: "untitled 8.txt".... I am not sure why two-way binding is not happening in this case

Comment: @Sheetal did the answer help?

Comment: @Sajeetharan when attachList is loaded the first time, the changes are seen. But when I add a new file after that, the changes are not getting reflected without page refresh. Meaning two-way binding is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the ng-controller directive or it is already defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling the **`populateView()`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.populateView = function() 
    {
      $scope.attachList = [];  $scope.attachList.push({fileId:"100",fileName:"Test.pdf"});
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-init="populateView()" class="col-xs-5">
       <ol class="marTop10">
        <li class="exactFit" ng-repeat="files in attachList">{{ files.fileName }}</li>
        </ol>
 </div>
```